# Split ArrayList each loop and add the middle value to the Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**1. Description**

I am making a Binary Search Tree which uses Level Order Insertion.
The reason for Level Order Insertion is because I need to make a
**Complete** Binary Search Tree.

**2. What I have done so far**

I have an `ArrayList` with these numbers:

> 5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80, 90, 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175, 200

The way I insert them is:

- The `insert` method checks if the number is higher or lower than the `root`. Lower means to the left of the `root`, higher means to the right of the `root`.
- The insertion into the `BST` starts by taking the middle of the `ArrayList` which is 90, and insert it into the `Tree`. This now becomes `root`.
- The next thing I to do is to break the `ArrayList` in two parts, the left half and the right half of the `ArrayList`:

> 5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80
>
> 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175, 200

- The next thing that is done is I take the middle of the halves and insert them into the `Tree`. The `Tree` is now 90 at `root`, 50 at left, and 150 at right.
- This should continue until there are no more elements to insert.

**3. Problem**

- My problem is that this is done manually, I want my method itself to break the `ArrayList` in half, take the middle of the two halves, break the two halves in 2 halves each, so we now have four halves, take the middle of each, insert them into the `Tree` and so on.
- I have tried to do this in a `for loop`, but I have no idea how to approach it.
- The reason I do not want to do it manually is that it should work with any `ArrayList` size, like size 3, size 7, size 15 etc.

This shows how I want it done:

> 5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80, 90, 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175, 200 = mid is 90
>
> ---
>
> 5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80 = mid is 50
>
> 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175, 200 = mid is 150
>
> ---
>
> 5, 20, 25 = mid is 20
>
> 66, 75, 80 = mid is 75
>
> ---
>
> 92, 95, 111 = mid is 95
>
> 166, 175, 200 = mid is 175
>
> ---
>
> 92, 111 = mid is 92
>
> 166, 200 = mid is 166

**4. Code**

This is the `insert` method which checks if the value is lower or higher than the `root`.

```
private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null);
        
        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

            if (compareResult < 0)
                t.left = insert(x, t.left);
            else if (compareResult > 0)
                t.right = insert(x, t.right);
            else
                ;  // Duplicate; do nothing

        return t;
    }
```

This is the method where I manually break the `ArrayList` in halves.

```
  public void createCompleteBinarySearchTree(ArrayList<Integer> list){

    Integer root = list.get(0) + (list.get(list.size()-1) - list.get(0)) / 2;
    Integer endOfMainArray = list.get(list.size() - 1);

    insert((AnyType) root);

    for(int i = 0; i <= list.size() -1; i++) {
        List<Integer> firstHalf = (List<Integer>) list.subList(0, root - 1);
        List<Integer> secondHalf = (List<Integer>) list.subList(root, endOfMainArray);

        Integer midOfFirstHalf = firstHalf.get(0) + (firstHalf.get(firstHalf.size() - 1) - firstHalf.get(0)) / 2;
        Integer midOfSecondHalf = secondHalf.get(0) + (secondHalf.get(secondHalf.size() - 1) - secondHalf.get(0)) / 2;


        insert((AnyType) midOfFirstHalf);

        insert((AnyType) midOfSecondHalf);

        insert((AnyType) firstHalf.get(0));

        insert((AnyType) firstHalf.get(2));

        insert((AnyType) secondHalf.get(0));

        insert((AnyType) secondHalf.get(2));
    }
}
```

This is the `ArrayList` which I insert from.

```
List<AnyType> numbers = new ArrayList<AnyType>((Collection<? extends AnyType>)
        Arrays.asList(5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80, 90, 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175, 200));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with a recursive structure so a recursive function can generally make things easy.

```
class BST<T> {
    T value;
    BST<T> left;
    BST<T> right;

    public BST(T[] contents) {
        insert(contents);
    }

    private void insert(T[] contents) {
        if (contents.length > 0) {
            if (contents.length == 1) {
                value = contents[0];
            } else {
                // Split it.
                int center = contents.length / 2;
                // Take the center value as my value
                value = contents[center];
                if (center > 0) {
                    // There is more to the left so put it in my `left` branch.
                    left = new BST<>(Arrays.copyOfRange(contents, 0, center));
                }
                if (center < contents.length) {
                    // ditto to the right.
                    right = new BST<>(Arrays.copyOfRange(contents, center + 1, contents.length));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return (left != null ? left.size() : 0)
                + (value != null ? 1 : 0)
                + (right != null ? right.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (left != null ? left.toString() + "," : "")
                + (value != null ? value : "")
                + (right != null ? "," + right.toString() : "");
    }
}

private void test(Integer[] integers) {
    System.out.println("Array = " + Arrays.toString(integers) + " length " + integers.length);
    BST<Integer> bst = new BST<>(integers);
    System.out.println("BST = " + bst.toString() + " length " + bst.size());
}

private void test() {
    test(new Integer[]{5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80, 90, 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175, 200});
    test(new Integer[]{5, 20, 25, 50, 66, 75, 80, 90, 92, 95, 111, 150, 166, 175});
    test(new Integer[]{90});
    test(new Integer[]{});
}
```

Comment: Will this still make the tree complete/perfect?

Comment: @mth-1417 Perhaps proving that yourself will help you understand what is happening here.

Comment: I have seen your code, and I can see that the center is always the mid of the array because you divide by 2. Then it checks if its greater or smaller of the root to check where to insert the next node. I can't seem to get what the purpose of the two test methods are since they only print the array out. I have made my own array in a main method I made. I then called the insert method and put my array as the parameter. I can't figure out how to print the tree out.

Comment: Okay I made my own level order and inorder method that traverses the tree and I can see it works! Thank you so much, I have been working so hard on this for a week and I couldn't figure it out. I just need to ask you if you could explain the recursiveness a bit more please :)?